# Bootstrap datepicker not working at all

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I've been trying to get bootstrap datepicker from here: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker to work but the calender won't show up at all. Not sure what I'm missing? I've linked everything correctly. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
<input type="text" value="02/16/12" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" class="datepicker" >

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>  
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: anything showing in the javascript console? And is your input really above the script tags or are you just condensing code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
})
```

It works on [here](http://jsfiddle.net/powtac/kGDGX/) I used jQuery 1.7.2, Bootstrap 2.0.2 and the latest [datepicker JS](https://raw.github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js). CSS is missing in my test, but the datepicker occurs on click! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I added this and it still doesn't seem to work. I'm putting it just before the </body> tag. The input is above the script tags.

Comment: Ok, I see, then the problem must be located somewhere else. Have you tried to run the JS in the FireBug console?

Comment: This is the error I get: TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
$('.datepicker').datepicker()            Any ideas?

Comment: It seems I was using the datepicker.js from here which must be an older version: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/    The one from here works perfect: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker Thanks for the help!

Comment: I know I'm late to the party but the jsfiddle test doesn't seem to work. There is nothing that happens onclick which is identical to the problem I'm having. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

You need to load jquery before you load bootstrap.js, in addition to adding the $(document).ready().

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>  
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps.